# Bootstrap 3 tabs not work correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

um developing a website and that should has few tabs according to my dream,
but thing is when I click a tab it shows only contents which is between heading tag,not P tags, 
Here's my code.please help me to fulfill my dream :-D

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" data-tabs="tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab1">Tab1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
        <h4>Heading1</h4>
        <p>text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
        <h4>Heading2</h4> 
        <p>text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">
        <h4>Heading3</h4>
        <p>text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Always add bootstrap css, js & jQuery links in the head whenever you are working with Bootstrap.

Comment: I added those things,but didnt get the result as I hope,thanks for your help :)

Comment: Run my answer below. Doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2):

I think you were missing the jQuery link.
The code works.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" data-tabs="tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
        <h4>Heading1</h4>
        <p>text in p</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
        <h4>Heading2</h4> 
        <p>text in p</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">
        <h4>Heading3</h4>
        <p>text in p</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Output :

[image][image]

Comment: No I added that jquery link.but it aint works for me
anyway div tag works inside that tab,.
thanks for you help friend. :)

Comment: ok.. but didn't the snippet above work? Run the code snippet.

Comment: yeah your code works perfectly,idk whats wrong about mine.

Comment: ok.. If this isn't working on your browser, check your console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Enable tabbable tabs via JavaScript

```
<script>
    $('.nav-pills a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $(this).tab('show')
    })
</script>
```

Comment: nope.still not works.anyway I can see tabs and also heading but inside of P tag.
thanks for your effort. :)